# How to redistribute BGP routes to OSPF using BIRD?

Tags: bgp, ospf

I have a router running BIRD. It is connected to network A using eBGP and B using OSPF. I want to let network B have routes to network A as another area (i.e. this is an area border router). How to achieve this?

Already tried adding the following to OSPF network B block:

```
area 1.2.3.4 {
    default cost 100;
    external {
            <Network A prefix>
            };
    };
};
```

but seems to be no use.

Comment: Having route received by a protocol (like BGP) sent to other routers via a different protocol (OSPF) is a process known as "redistribution". Almost all systems have a "redistribute" command within the protocol configuration to do this. You have to look in BIRD documentation how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out this myself. Have to add `import all;` or some custom import filter in OSPF block.